# Day switch with month when i use len formula to remove 1s space

Tags: excel, vba

I really don't understand whats happen and why this in my worksheet.

To remove the first space from some cells i use this code:

```
Sub RoundedRectangle5_Click()


Dim Cel As Range, Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("B7:C37")
For Each Cel In Rng
    If IsEmpty(Cel.Value) = False Then
   Cel.Value = Right(Cel.Value, Len(Cel.Value) - 1)
    End If
Next Cel


End Sub
```

But then in a specific cell where i have a data, after use this code, the day and month switch like: if initial data was `10-04-2017`, after code is change to `04-10-2017`. I thought that only the format changed, but the data actually changed from 10th April to 4th Oct. Any one know why this is happening?

Comment: What do you expect to see in the cell when you remove the first character from `10-04-2017` using VBA?

Comment: OH, also, there is nothing in your code that ensures the first character of the cell will be a `space`.  If it is not, you may get other results.

Comment: pnuts, nope, when the day is greather than 12 it doesn't change, but apear as text, cause when i apply a filtre it appear 13/04/2017, instead (+)2017->(+)April->13.

Comment: Can you try with this solution = `Cel.Value = Trim(Cel.Value)`?

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld, all 1st character in this case are spaces. Our design/marketing team (dumb team) though that is nice to make a pdf image appear in mail messenge, with all 1st characters being a space -.-
This excel is used to regist the data i get by email, about patients and antibiotics prescription. i only slect the mail and past in the right place in excel, then i remove the spaces and insert in a "data base" (other worksheet).

Comment: @Tiago pnuts answer is correct.  You have USA date system.  And when the "day" is > 12, the string remains a text string; otherwise it will convert to a date according to your Windows regional settings

Comment: Vityata, nothing happen... it doesn't remove the 1st space

Comment: @RonRosenfeld how i can change to EU date system? :/ Thanks all

Comment: You can change your Windows Regional Settings -- that would change it for your entire computer.  You could also change your VBA routine to account for dates in EU settings.  I'll write something up.  VBA might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification to your code.

- Test to make sure there is data in the cell
- Is the data a date with a leading `space`?
- If so, convert it using TextToColumns
- Also note for the non-dates, the use of the `MID` function which, in VBA, has an optional `length` parameter.

---

```
For Each Cel In Rng
    If IsEmpty(Cel.Value) = False Then
            If IsDate(Cel.Value) And _
            Left(Cel.Text, 1) = Chr(32) Then
                Cel.TextToColumns Destination:=Cel, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                    Tab:=False, semicolon:=False, comma:=False, Space:=True, other:=False, _
                    fieldinfo:=Array(Array(1, xlSkipColumn), Array(2, xlDMYFormat))
            Else
                Cel.Value = Mid(Cel.Text, 2)
            End If
    End If
Next Cel
```

There are other ways to convert.  If you are certain of the delimiter, you could just use the `Split` function and combine using  `Dateserial`

e.g:

```
Dim V as variant
For Each Cel In Rng
    If IsEmpty(Cel.Value) = False Then
            If IsDate(Cel.Value) Then
                V = Split(Mid(Cel.Text, 2), "-")
                Cel.Value = DateSerial(V(2), V(1), V(0))
            Else
                Cel.Value = Mid(Cel.Text, 2)
            End If
    End If
Next Cel
```

Comment: the 1st code remove the 1st space very well but date continue to change :7

Comment: Strange, if i use your 1st code the 1st spaces are removed but date change, if i used the code from Vityata, after yours only date change again for the initial date :/ Strange?!?

Comment: @Tiago Yes, it is much more difficult to solve problems and troubleshoot when not supplied with actual data.  Are you sure that this time it is the date that is changing? and not just the format?  If it is the actual date, supply some data, in the form of a downloadable document, that demonstrates the problem so we can reproduce it.